# Matlab - string containing a number and equal sign

Tags: matlab, file, file-io

I have a data file that contains parameter names and values with an equal sign in between them.  It's like this:

```
A = 1234
B = 1353.335
C = 
D = 1
```

There is always one space before and after the equal sign.  The problem is some variables don't have values assigned to them like "C" above and I need to weed them out.

I want to read the data file (text) into a cell and just remove the lines with those invalid statements or just create a new data file without them.

Whichever is easier, but I will eventually read the file into a cell with textscan command.

The values (numbers) will be treated as double precision.

Please, help.

Thank you,

Eric

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
fid = fopen('file.txt'); %// open file
x = textscan(fid, '%s', 'delimiter', '\n'); %// or '\r'. Read each line into a cell
fclose(fid); %// close file
x = x{1}; %// each cell of x contains a line of the file
ind = ~cellfun(@isempty, regexp(x, '=\s[\d\.]+$')); %// desired lines: space, numbers, end
x = x(ind); %// keep only those lines
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to get the variables, and reject lines that do not have any character, this might work (the data.txt is just a txt generated by the example of data you have given):

```
fid = fopen('data.txt');

tline = fgets(fid);
while ischar(tline)
    tmp = cell2mat(regexp(tline,'\=(.*)','match'));
    b=str2double(tmp(2:end));
    if ~isnan(b)
        disp(b)
    end
    tline = fgets(fid);
end

fclose(fid);
```

I am reading the txt file line by line, and using general expressions to get rid of useless chars, and then converting to double the value read.

Comment: Actual parameter names are a lot more complicated such as pos_rudder_UPR or pressure_cylinder_LWR. Will the code above still work?

Comment: I edited my answer. For this Input A = 1234
B = 1353.335
C = 
D = 1
pressure_cylinder_LWR = 8
pos_rudder_UPR = 
p1 = 3

it returns   1234,  1.3533e+003, 1,  8, 3